# How to give a beep sound at 45 sec

Tags: android, call, alert, duration

How to create an Android app to give a beep sound before approaching the 1 min mark (Say at 45 sec, just a beep to let the user knowing, 15 sec before it passes a min)?

Comment: What does the beep have to do with the SQLLite table?  Is this an app for Android?

Comment: What have you programmed so far?  Unless you can provide a SSCCE, we can't help you.  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native MediaPlayer for this purpose.

```
  new CountDownTimer(//put time required here) {

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timeUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //get time remaining here
    }

}.start();
```

Create an Uri using 
Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

and then a ringtone - and call play().